# How to remove reflections from images?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, ica, image-processing

I've been playing around with making images better and removing all the unwanted disturbances from it. I found out a major concern would be removing the unwanted reflections that might come.

I've gone through a [paper](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/6675/AIM-1647.pdf?sequence=2) that uses [ICA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis) to get rid of these reflections. What other methods would work?

Say I have an image:

[image]

Another image:

[image]

Converted it into CMYK

[image]

How should i remove this semi black portion?

Comment: Note that the approach described in the paper you have linked to requires two images with a different polarization. Do you have similar requirements? 1/ Should this work automatically or is human supervision allowed? 2/ Should this work from a single image or is it OK to require the user to produce various images of the same scene? 3/ Should this work with any photographic image or is it OK to require the use of special filters/optical devices on the camera?

Comment: Well its not neccessary to use the same approach as they have proposed and i don't have two images just many images with reflections that i would like to make as less as possible

Comment: Did you read other papers too? I get loads of relevant hits with the queries "blind image separation", "glare removal", and "reflection removal".

Comment: Yes i found all of it most techniques are really complex and would take time for understanding what if this could be solved with easier techniques like filtering

Comment: Your problem *is* complex; deceptively so. I do not think there is an easy way out. It's a testament to the ability of our brain that it seems otherwise.

Comment: there is always a way of finding such methods :) i guess ill embark on that journey

Comment: Do you have multiple frames of motion?  I don't think there's any way to identify the reflection from a single static image.  The reflection information and other information has to be separable somehow.

Comment: maybe i can split the image into different planes as in convert it into 3D or something would that work?

Comment: @vini: Do you have any information other than a single static image?

Comment: i have many such images  ...mostly with a front view and sum having taken from behind a window

Comment: @vini: Multiple images of the same scene?  That might make it possible.  Can you post examples?

Comment: I was looking for something else and saw your question as a related of what I was looking for. I'm not an expert in this area either, but Sing Bing Kang et al. from MSFT Research did some studies a long time ago about reflections and the results were quite good: http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=67274 Though this is not an answer that will solve your problem, I just wanted to share with you the link just in case it points you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 6):

I am not a specialist in image processing but I highly doubt this is feasible with your requirements (single image, no prior information). The challenges is twofold:

- Detect which area of the image is a reflection. This looks like a quite complex scene understanding problem. In your example, I know that the right side is a reflection because I can infer from the image that a person is depicted here, and I have prior knowledge about what the back of a person looks like.
- Reconstruct the background in the identified region. While it would be possible to just inpaint the area detected as a reflection with textures from the surrounding, the result would hide many details! Whatever I've seen in the field of *single input* image separation was relying on very simple image models (stationary textures), not real world images. The more traditional image separation setups (multiple channels, recto/verso of translucent pages, multiple polarization) do not apply to your case.

Comment: what are the tradition image separation setups that you referring to ?

Comment: One example is when scanning recto/verso documents. The text on one side of the page "bleeds" through the other side (http://ars.sciencedirect.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0031320311003049-gr6.jpg). This is close to a traditional BSS setup since you have 2 sources, and 2 observations of the same sources with different mixture weights. Another examples are in multi-channel image analysis in astrophysics. These situations where you have as many images as sources to extract are the most commonly explored in the image separation literature.